# Different color schemes inside one stylesheet

Tags: css

I have different styles for my theme (different color schemes).

First I load the default css and secondly a css stylesheet with particular colors, etc depending on what color scheme I want to use.

Testing the speed of my site, I have noticed a delay because I need to load two style-sheets.

Is there a way to put all styles inside one file and not use two different ones? Also this has to be cross browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the color overrides you could nest them within an id selector, and give that id to the body element in order to choose a color scheme. This will allow you to store many themes in one file.

For example

```css
/* defaults */
h1 { color : black; }

/* light theme */
#light h1 { color : grey; } 

/* neon theme */
#neon h1 { color : pink; }
```

Then set the body class, as

```css
<body id="neon">
```

If you are using LESS you can easily wrap the top-level style around your entire colour scheme to keep the layout neater. e.g.

```css
#light {
    h1 { color : grey; } 
    p { color : silver; }
}
```

Comment: It's a better idea to use an id as your theme indicator, so in your case #light and #neon. This is due to the fact id's are a stronger selector in CSS

Answer (score 0):

You should not really notice a huge delay in loading two style sheets vs loading one.

However, to answer your question, you can copy all of the contents of the second stylesheet file to the end of the first one and you should end up with the same result.

Comment: Yes but how do i select between scheme colors and other css rules? I need some condition for the browser to be able to load the needed rules. Right now I am doing it with php

Comment: Ahh this isn't really a problem of which stylesheet to load. I would load all stylesheets necessary, and then use html ids or classes to determine which style to apply to which content. See martinCzerwi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

When copying all the styles into one file, you could define two classes for body, and prefix all the styles with the according class.

So you could have `<body class="scheme1">` and your CSS-Rules would be like `.scheme1 h1 {}`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server side technology, you should "bundle" your CSS and JS, so they will get served to the client as one file.
This will also enable you to compress and minify your .js and .css.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [less](http://lesscss.org/) and minify you CSS.

You should use a multiple classe like for example you could to thisM
Or just minify you CSS.

```
<h1 class="big-text theme-blue"></h1>
```

then in you css you use rules such asM

```
.big-text.theme-blue
```

Comment: You did not answer the OP's question entirely, it's not only minifying it's also about multiple color schemes

Answer (score 0):

I have various color schemes inside a single stylesheet.  To demonstrate changing the color scheme go to http://prettydiff.com/ and change the value on the color scheme list to a different value.  All this does is just change the class attribute on the body tag, which then refers to different CSS properties in the one CSS file.

The stylesheet is at http://prettydiff.com/diffview.css